# Send Compatible pointer block types with AWSContinuationBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services

I'm getting the following error when trying to run a block with AWSS3TransferManager:

```
incompatible block pointer types sending 'id ((^)(void)) to parameter of type 'AWSContinuationBlock' (aka id (^)(AWSTask *__strong))
```

I believe this is due to different block types where I am currently not returning any value while it expects an AWSTask, but I'm not sure how to return an AWSTask.

```
_uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];

AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
[[transferManager upload:_uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task){

    if (task.error){
        NSLog(@"%@",task.error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming `BFTask` to `AWSTask` and returning that in the block?

Comment: Thanks! I had found some starter code with BFTask and figured I had to configure it using Bolts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to the block you are providing expecting a `BFTask` parameter.

Change the `BFTask` parameter to an `AWSTask` and return that.

```
_uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];

AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
[[transferManager upload:_uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task){

    if (task.error){
        NSLog(@"%@",task.error);
    }

    return task;
}];
```